# How to generate a foreign key for a Many-to-one relationship (unidirectional)?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, foreign-keys, many-to-one

I want to have an entity that have a many to one relationship with another entity, but with generated foreign key using JPA (no foreign key in the database), is it possible?

I know there is a solution using one to many and many to one, but I want to only have a many to one, because I only want it to be a unidirectional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`, both in unidirectional and bidirectional way. Obviously, when you have a many-to-one relation from one side, you will have a one-to-many from the opposite side. 
Also, you should note that only one foreign key in the many-side to one-side can handle this relation.

If you use `@JoinColumn(name="some_column_name")` just below one of the `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToOne` annotations, the hbm2ddl should be able to create the proper foreign key in your table.

However, try not to rely on hbm2ddl and maintain the database schema yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to be sure there was no other way to just have a ‛‛‛ManyToOne‛‛‛